# Installing Xcode 4 / iOS SDK 4.3

Tags: mac, xcode, ios

I just bought, downloaded and installed Xcode 4 through the Mac App Store.

The [Xcode 4 detail page in the App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id422352214) says:

> Xcode 4 runs on Mac OS X Snow Leopard and includes the Xcode IDE, Instruments, **iOS Simulator**, the latest Mac OS X and **iOS SDKs**, and hundreds of powerful features

However, when I open the iOS Simulator application, it’s still at the same version as before I upgraded to Xcode 4, i.e. version 4.2 / build 235.

Am I missing something? Do I still have to do something special to get the iOS Simulator to the latest version?

I realize iOS SDK 4.3 can be downloaded together with Xcode 3.2.6 via [Apple’s iOS Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/) but I’d rather not download another 4 GB just to get the iOS Simulator I should’ve gotten when installing Xcode 4 in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try doing the following:

1 - Open the Xcode menu and select "Preferences..."

2 - Go to "Downloads"

3 - Select "Components"

You will be able to install the iOS 4.3 Simulator from there.

Hope it helps.